# Extract XML from SOAP envelope in c#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have a response from web service in SOAP envelope as follows:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
  <ProcessTranResponse xmlns="http://www.polaris.co.uk/XRTEService/2009/03/">
    <ProcessTranResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XRTEService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <a:PrintFormFileNameContents i:nil="true"/>
      <a:ResponseXML>response_message</a:ResponseXML>
    </ProcessTranResult>
  </ProcessTranResponse>
</s:Body>
```

And I want to get `response_message` to a string variable. I tried doing

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(Response);
XNamespace xmlnsa = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XRTEService";
var ResponseXML = doc.Descendants(xmlnsa + "ResponseXML");
```

And when I use watch I see in `ResponseXML -> Results View[0] -> Value` my `response_message`, but I can't figure out what is the next step to get to Value from C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`XContainer.Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx) returns a collection of elements. You should then try something like this:

```
foreach (XElement el in ResponseXML)
{
    Console.WriteLine(el.Value);
}
```

Or you can do something like this if you know that there is always only one response:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(Response);

XNamespace xmlnsa = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XRTEService";

XElement ResponseXML = (from xml in XMLDoc.Descendants(xmlnsa + "ResponseXML")
                        select xml).FirstOrDefault();

string ResponseAsString = ResponseXML.Value;
```

Comment: Also doc.Descendants(xmlnsa + "ResponseXML").First().Value; using Linq worked. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Be aware that `.First()` may throw an exception if the descendants list is empty...

Comment: And `ResponseXML.Value` will throw an exception if `FirstOrDefault` returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can employ several solutions to meet your purpose while you may wanna introduce the structure of xml content or not.

**Static attitude**

You can simply use this:

```
XmlDocument _doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(_stream.ReadToEnd());
```

Then find the desired data with something like this:

```
doc.LastChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.LastChild.InnerText;
```

**Read xml structure**

You can write some additional lines of code to introduce namespaces and other xml contents to find/map the available data, by taking a look at [extracting-data-from-a-complex-xml-with-linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073260/extracting-data-from-a-complex-xml-with-linq)